# How to get data from an Object from another Class?

Tags: c#, .net, object

Hey I have a problem with my code.
Sorry if the question is too easy but I can't find a solution.

I have an object called **user** in **class 1**

The Object User has this variables.

```
 public class User
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string mobilenumber { get; set; }
    public string service { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{email}: {password}: {mobilenumber}: {service}";
    }
}
```

These variables are filled with data in class 1

Now I want to access these data in class 2 and display them to me.

I tried something like

```
Class Firstclass{
    public void OnLogin(){
        public User user = new User();
        user.email = abc@abc.com
   }
}

Class B{
   protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
    Firstclass firstclass = new Firstclass();
    string output = firstclass.user.email;
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you show in the second snippet won't fly outside of a method. You could put it inside `Firstclass`'s Constructor for example.

Comment: it's quite odd to have the instance of User hardcoded like that in Firstclass.. anyway to make your desiderata something meaningful for the c# syntax, this would be an attempt: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CwGu90

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that. A simple one would be to instantiate the User inside the constructor:

```
public Class Firstclass
{
    User user;        
    public FirstClass()
    {
       this.user = new User();
       this.user.email = "abc@abc.com";
       // more data could be here or use a local method to fill user's fields
    }
    public User 
    {
      get
      {
         return this.user;
      }
      set
      {
         this.user = value;
      }
    }
 }
```

Try to avoid using a public field, rather use a public property like User in above. Then in Class B, you would have:

```
Class B
{
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Firstclass firstclass = new Firstclass();
        string output = firstclass.User.email;
    }
}
```